# How to remove accidental double commit [Git]

Tags: git, commit, rebase, merge-conflict-resolution, assembla

I'm looking for a way to remove an "double" commit I accidentally created on a repo. While attempting to collapse a branch's commits before merging it into the master, I unwittingly pushed the branch's changes onto the master (I know just enough Git to shoot myself in the foot). Later, when I merged the branch, I ended up with a second (merge) commit. The changes in this merge commit are exactly the same as those in the accidentally pushed commit. Now my master commit history looks something like this:

```
Some_Newer_Stuff_Here
The_Merge_Commit
The_Branch_Commit //Same contents, different Hash as commit above
Master_Commit_2
Master_Commit_1
```

I have attempted to use git interactive rebase (as detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21468190/git-remove-duplicate-commits) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22817360/fixing-git-double-commit-history)), however when I do so, not all the commits appear in the list. Instead I see something like this:

```
Some_Newer_Stuff_Here
The_Branch_Commit
Master_Commit_2
```

The_Merge_Commit is missing (which I assume is the one I want to keep). Note that all commits do show up in `git log`. If I attempt to remove The_Branch_Commit using `rebase` it creates a bunch of merge conflicts.

I can't find any way to solve this problem, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [fixing git double commit history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22817360/fixing-git-double-commit-history?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: If you run `git show <merge-commit-hash>`, does anything show up?  Also, if you could run `git log --oneline --graph --all -20` and paste the output here, it would really help!

Comment: You already have "Some_Newer_Stuff_Here", so you can't do anything about the history anymore because someone already made changes based on your merge commit. If you change the history and force-push, it will break things when other team members start pulling the changes. So forget about this, mistakes happen, move on.

Comment: @Zach Posten `git show` does come up with a commit.
`git log` is too many characters for a comment so I put it on [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/nPNtYNbH)
For reference `The_Merge_Commit` is b5151cf and `The_Branch_Commit` is 84939ca.
I'm sure the repo looks pretty bad, unfortunately I have basically no clue how to use Git correctly.

Comment: Does your `git reflog` show a point in time when everything is hunky dorey? perhaps you can rewind to that point in time, then force push?

Comment: @NiallBurton I really want to help you get this figured out!  Unfortunately, the pastebin you created doesn't contain commit b5151cf.  That's my fault because I specified the `-20` in the command I posted above.  Could you possibly create a new one that includes all the relevant commits?  If you omit the `-20` from above, you can just copy the commits that are relevant

Answer (score 0):

Without more commit information, I'm not able to give you specific, step by step instructions.  But I thought I could potentially answer one of the aspects of your question.

The reason that `The_Merge_Commit` doesn't show up in the interactive rebase is because the `git rebase` command by default ignores merge commits, instead preferring to lay commits one on top of the next.

You can change this behavior with the `--preserve-merges` flag however.  Adding that to your `git rebase -i` command will cause `The_Merge_Commit` to show up in the editor page, and then you would be able to delete `The_Branch_Commit`.  But there is still the potential for some annoying merge conflicts to happen.

```
git rebase -i --preserve-merges <HASH-OF-COMMIT-BEFORE-INCIDENT>
```

Comment: If this repo happens to be open source, I would be happy to take a look at it for you.